# How could I list all helm variables within a chart?

Tags: go, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

The helm chart is very big, I want to sort out a values map document to help other participant to understand every value.
I tried to figure this out in 2 ways, but I don't have any finding so far.

1. I'm trying to use helm template verbose, maybe it will print the argument every time it filled with value. But it not expected as I thought.
2. I searched golang template, to expect any tool can print the variables of a file/dirs. No finding.

So my question is,

1. Is it meaningful of sort all the argument into a document and comment it.

- if 1 is yes, how could I manage it?
- if 1 is no, can you offer some ways for let other participant(op, intern) understand the project asap?